# Application Crashed - Wired Crash

Tags: iphone, ipad

What does this error mean?

```
Nov  8 17:57:10 unknown configd[25] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel memory event (91), free: 670, active: 2840, inactive: 2253, purgeable: 0, wired: 15143
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown SpringBoard[92] <Warning>: Received memory warning. Level=2
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown MobileMail[6432] <Warning>: Received memory warning. Level=2
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown configd[25] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobileipod[0xe0a1]) Exited: Killed: 9
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0xbebe]) Exited: Killed: 9
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:paradigm.PaymentSystemiPad[0x6c80]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3795 (24506):0
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown DTMobileIS[6377] <Warning>: _memoryNotification : <NSThread: 0x1c5361d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[6480] <Warning>: 1 [1950/1503]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ff669f0, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:paradigm.PaymentSystemiPad[0x6c80]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3794 (24506):3
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:paradigm.PaymentSystemiPad[0x6c80]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3202 (24506):10
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:paradigm.PaymentSystemiPad[0x6c80]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:paradigm.PaymentSystemiPad[0x6c80]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov  8 17:57:11 unknown SpringBoard[92] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Nov  8 17:57:12 unknown DTMobileIS[6377] <Warning>: _memoryNotification : {
        OSMemoryNotificationLevel = 0;
        timestamp = "2011-11-08 12:27:11 +0000";
    }
Nov  8 17:57:12 unknown DTMobileIS[6377] <Warning>: _memoryNotification : <NSThread: 0x1c5361d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Nov  8 17:57:12 unknown DTMobileIS[6377] <Warning>: _memoryNotification : {
        OSMemoryNotificationLevel = 0;
        timestamp = "2011-11-08 12:27:12 +0000";
    }
Nov  8 17:57:12 unknown SpringBoard[92] <Warning>: Application 'PaymentSystemiPad' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov  8 17:57:12 unknown SpringBoard[92] <Warning>: Application 'iPod' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Nov  8 17:57:12 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[6486] Builtin profile: MobileMail (sandbox)
Nov  8 17:57:13 unknown ReportCrash[6485] <Error>: libMobileGestalt loadBasebandMobileEquipmentInfo: CommCenter error: 1:45
Nov  8 17:57:13 unknown ReportCrash[6485] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary
Nov  8 17:57:13 unknown ReportCrash[6485] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2011-11-08-175713.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Nov  8 17:59:12 unknown SpringBoard[92] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(1f55bf50) uilock state: 0 -> 1
```

Comment: Post crash log, console log doesn't give any info on why application crashed.

Comment: It crashed because of memory Issue

Comment: I didn't get any device logs.

Answer (score 1):

This mean that you have allocated a lot of memory and **Received memory warning.** I assume you have memory leaks or load many images/resources into memory. Try to research your code and find places where you load resources.

Comment: In my application there are almost 50 textfields and 3 images. I am getting level-1 and level-2 memory warnings. whenever I receive warnings I am releasing objects in didReceiveMemoryWarning and recreating them in viewDidLoad. Still my application is crashing.

Comment: hm, i don't think that textfields are cause of crashing. What are the sizes of your images?

Comment: 2 images are of {700,385} size & the 3rd one is {768 × 2933}. I am converting these images into data & attaching them to an email.

Comment: ok. check how much time you attached these images (just put breakpoint to that line). Only 40 Mb per 1 app are available in iphone memory. so, if you load more then you will receive warnings.